# how to refresh data of 3rd party widget in angular js partial files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am including YOTPO reviews on my angular js website. 
Its a two step process -
1) Include their widget.js - I have included this on my index.html, where all other js files have also been included
2) Include their widget's div tag the page where reviews have to be displayed - I have included this on individual product page, which is a partial/product.html

Issue -
My site is a search website. Index.html has a search box, all the results are displayed there. When user clicks on a particular page in results, he gets redirected to particular product page (partial/product.html)

User Flow -
Lets assume, on search I get products P1, P2, P3 in results.

For the first time, If i click on P1 and go to its product page, YOTPO review appears.
But when I go back to search and click on any other result (even with new search query and results) - YOTPO widget doesnot appear. But if i refresh the page, it appears.

I think reviews are displayed when widgets.js is called (which is included in index.html) and refresh reloads it. 
But How do i make sure that its reloaded everytime user navigates to product page?
Or how is this scenario handled in angularJS - I am new to JS, may be I am missing some concept here.

Answer (score 3):

Hey I'm working on a React/Redux application so it may not be the same.

When you have the yotpo sitewide script, it should create an object, yotpo (if you console.log(yotpo) you can see it).  If you look in the **proto**, there are a number of functions in there.

The products are pulled in by the product ID, whether parent or child sku or however you have it.

I was having an issue where it wasn't updating the widget if we went to a new product, but would render right if I refreshed.

This is how I solved it; I put this code into the function where it is re-rendering:

```
// update Yotpo dynamically
  window.yotpo.initialized = false;
  window.yotpo.clean();

// there is a widgets array that the widgets are pulling data from; we need to update this
  for (let i = 0, len = window.yotpo.widgets.length; i < len; i++) {
    window.yotpo.widgets[i].settings.pid = nextProps.product.id;
    window.yotpo.widgets[i].settings.main_widget_pid = nextProps.product.id;
  }
  setTimeout(() => window.yotpo.initWidgets(), 500);
```

I'm not sure if that fixes your specific issue but hopefully it can at least point you in the right direction.

For you, you might just have to run window.yotpo.initWidgets() when that div is re-rendered.

Answer (score 3):

For my VueJS SPA I've used the following code in `mounted()`:

```
if (
  typeof yotpo != 'undefined'
  && yotpo
  && yotpo.initialized
  && !document.querySelector('.yotpo-display-wrapper')
) {
  (new Yotpo.API(yotpo)).refreshWidgets()
}
```

found method on https://support.yotpo.com/en/article/loading-yotpo-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the "Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM" section of this page.

[Angular Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

I am not familiar with YOTPO, but I am willing to guess you could create a updateReview function within the link function of a custom directive that would be called every time you need to update the reviews.  That would most likely be an excellent place to start, since now it sounds like the code is only being executed when a certain view is loaded.

Comment: Thanks user2263572 for putting it out so nicely. I am gonna try using Directive for this. But as you said, I create a function and call it once the review is updated. The problem that I am facing is that Reviews are being shown once i refresh the page, but not when i land on the page first time. Did i make any sense?

Comment: Not sure how your app is setup so it's difficult to provide any more feedback.  How are you handling routing in your app?  If you are using something like angular ui-router that will probably help solve this issue.  Chances are you are just executing the code prior to your view being loaded.